# Add button to the flex accordion header which can clickable

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I want to add a button with a cross to the header of the accordion which can be clickable. that means i want to display a message when the some one click on that button. i go through many of the samples in the web but couldn't get it done. if any one who knows do this in flex4 it will very helpful.

I tried with also a CanvasButtonAccordionHeader, it shows the button but when i click it, it didn't give the message although i created the click event handler.

if somebody know how to resolve this please describe it with a simple source code.

thanx.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that by customizing the header in CSS.

**Add the header Style to you accordion.**
`<mx:Accordion id="accordion"
            headerStyleName="accHeader"
            width="100%" />`

**In your CSS**
`.accHeader {
         fillColors: haloSilver, haloBlue;
         fillAlphas: 1.0, 0.5;
         selectedFillColors: black, black;
        }`
Or embed your image in here.

You can place that message in your ViewStack.

Answer (score 0):

I use the CanvasButtonAccordionHeader in Flex 3, so not sure if this will work in Flex 4.

But.... in case it's of any use, I create my CanvasButtonAccordianHeader as a custom componant which dispatches an event when the button is clicked:

```
<CanvasButtonAccordionHeader xmlns="flexlib.containers.accordionClasses.*"  
 xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" mouseChildren="true" 
   <mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
            [Bindable]
        private var itemName:String;
        public function init():void{
            itemName=data.name;

        }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:Metadata>
    [Event(name="homeButtonClicked")]
</mx:Metadata>
<mx:HBox width="100%" horizontalAlign="right" height="100%" 
    paddingRight="5"
    verticalAlign="middle">
    <mx:LinkButton label="&lt;&gt;"              
        click="dispatchEvent(new Event('homeButtonClicked'));"
        />

</mx:HBox>

 </CanvasButtonAccordionHeader>
```

Then I instantiate the custom componant at the bottom of the Accordian as a Header Renderer:

............................................

```
<mx:headerRenderer>
<mx:Component>      
<applicationLayout:AccordionNavHeaderRenderer   
                                            homeButtonClicked="outerDocument.dispatchEvent(new Event('homeClick'))"/>

    </mx:Component>
</mx:headerRenderer>
</mx:Accordion>
```

Hope this is of use.